Python Module Missing- Moved python Virtual Environment to new Machine
I moved a python virtual environment (PVE) from computer A running python 3.10.11 to computer B running python 3.12.4
seems this caused the modules of my PVE to stop working.
What would be the simplest way to fix?
I would like to think i could run a few commands on the PVE to get it to work on the newer version of python.
i would prefer to avoid
1)a reinstall of the python modules on computer B
2)installing the older version of python on computer B that i was using on computer A
The paths to my PVEs are the same on each computer- C:\pyvms\myPVE_1
after looking through this article i'm guessing the wrong pip version is being invoked. just not sure what to do about it.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+move

Python virtual environments are not relocatable. Moving a virtualenv to a different host is error-prone even with the same Python version. With a different Python version it's guaranteed not to work. The only way is to recreate.
